# How to extract all information (including the info that is not shown) from a HTML object

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract all the articles of Jean Tirole from Google scholar (url: https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=ZEDUm5UAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=title). After downloading the url I tried the following:

```
tirole_parent <- read_html("jean_tirole_GoogleScholarCitations.html")
tirole_table <- tirole_parent %>% 
                html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="gsc_a_b"]') %>% 
                html_nodes(xpath = "tr") %>%
                html_nodes(xpath = "td") %>%
                html_text()
```

However, this only gave me the first 20 articles. How can I get all the articles from the HTML?

Comment: what you want to take from the page ? the name of the article ?

Answer (score 1):

1. if you are looking to grep the title name so the correct name of it is `gsc_a_at`
2. when you press on `Show More`, Actually it's make an `XHR` request with the following parameters which is `cstart` and `pagesize`.
3. `cstart` is the page to start from it. and `pagesize` is the total result per page and the maximum of it is `100`.
4. the total result is `660` so i will start from 0 till 660.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for start in range(0, 700, 100):
    r = requests.get(
        f"https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=ZEDUm5UAAAAJ&view_op=list_works&sortby=title&cstart={start}&pagesize=100")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
    for item in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'gsc_a_at'}):
        print(item.text)
```

You can check the output online via [That Link](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/Tets)